# installing mod_security causing apache service start to fail

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

I installed mod security using this tutorial [http://www.linuxmaza....](http://www.linuxmaza.com/apache/how-to-install-mod-security-on-linux-centos-5-4-fedora-12/) . After installing I got the error described and followed the steps to solve it.  The only thing I did differently was updating apache from the repo rather than uninstalling first.

Apache fails on restart, the error log tell me this :

Update: I uninstalled apache and did a clean install. Still getting the same error though.

```
[Mon Feb 20 16:45:24 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 20 16:45:35 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Feb 20 16:45:35 2012] [alert] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: mod_unique_id:    unable to find IPv4 address of "astinf"
Configuration Failed
```

Comment: Is there any *particular* reason you're using those instructions and not just doing `yum install mod_security` ?

Comment: @Ladadadada I didn't have it installed in my yum repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of Googling on that error suggests that you have `astinf` (I'm guessing this is your username...) in your Apache config for the `ServerName` directive.

You can either change your `ServerName` to something that will return an IP address (such as `localhost`) or add an entry for whatever you have in there into your `/etc/hosts` file.

If you have problems with that, [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/294006/26130) suggests that SELinux can get in the way of Apache reading your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: astinf isn't listed as the server name apaches config, I've tryed using my domain and localhost with no luck.  Strace brings up the same response as the guy got in the question you linked.  But his solution doesn't work....

Comment: @FrankAstin Where's it listed, then?  Clearly Apache's getting that from somewhere, and it's not just a coincidental random string.  We're just guessing if you don't provide your configuration, and information about where `astinf` is used on this system.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I'm thinking the same, but it's definitely not in httpd.conf or hosts. It was originally the server name (when I bought the VPS I entered it as the server name) . Where else apache could be getting it from?

Comment: What about any files included by httpd.conf?

Comment: Time for some grep magic.  `grep -r astinf /etc/httpd` should tell you where it is.

Comment: @Ladadadada got it, `/etc/sysconfig/network:HOSTNAME=astinf` . So should I change that too my domain?

Comment: Ok changed network hostname to my domain, still getting the same error.

Comment: @Ladadadada I just need to update the hostname in VPS control panel. Thanks for your help.